# MongoDB search using text index not working c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, indexing, query-builder

I have Added text index on my collection. I am trying to filter the data with text search with some additional filters. But It is not working well with other filters.

```
{$text:{$search:"test"},Type:"5"}
```

The above query returns all 42 entries matching the criteria from mongoDB Atlas.

But when I am doing this from c# I think I am querying it wrong. What am I missing here.

```
 var collection = db.GetCollection<TestTbl>("TestTbl");
            var filter = Builders<TestTbl>.Filter.Text(searchtext)
            &Builders<TestTbl>.Filter.Eq("TypeID", TypeID);
var data = collection.Find(filter).ToList();
```

here data is returned null.

When I am giving text only in the filter it works fine.

```
{$text:{$search:"test"}}
var collection = db.GetCollection<TestTbl>("TestTbl");
                var filter = Builders<TestTbl>.Filter.Text(searchtext);
    var data = collection.Find(filter).ToList();
```

Comment: Try concatenating your filters with And:
`var filter = Builders<TestTbl>.Filter.And(Builders<TestTbl>.Filter.Text(searchtext), Builders<TestTbl>.Filter.Eq("TypeID", TypeID))`

Comment: The Error was with my model it was Guid Type forgot to mention the bsontype string for the field representation.  Thanks @Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Error was with my model it was Guid Type forgot to mention the bsontype string for the field representation